# Using text from cell to match title to obtain cell below with Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to fetch the text of a cell from a table where the title matches "Make" in the another cell in the same table row.

For example, in the code example below I am trying to fetch the text "Lako" from the `<a>` within a `<td>` (cell) and it needs to match the title "Make" in the `<td>` (cell) above within the same `<tr>`(row). Unfortunately, all other tables have the same layout

I have tried the following, but it did not work:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tr[contains(text(), "Make")]/td[@class="value"]/a')
```

Example code:

```
<tbody><tr>
    <td class="title">Website ref. :</td>
    <td class="value">7334892</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td class="title">Bodywork</td>
    <td class="value"><a title="used car carrier semi-trailer" href="/car-carrier-semi-trailer/1-35-v88/used-car-carrier-semi-trailer.html" onclick="gtag('event', 'click', {'event_category': 'technicalSheet', 'event_label': 'listing-var', 'value': ''});"> Car carrier </a>
    </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td class="title">Make</td>
    <td class="value"><a href="/lako-car-carrier-semi-trailer/~a1b35c88e2161/lako-car-carrier.html" title="Lako car carrier semi-trailer" onclick="gtag('event', 'click', {'event_category': 'technicalSheet', 'event_label': 'listing-brd', 'value': ''});"><span>Lako</span></a></td>
</tr><tr>
        <td class="title">Model</td>
        <td class="value">DUPLO PISO</td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td class="title">Condition</td>
    <td class="value">Used</td>
</tr><tr>
        <td class="title">Date of first registration</td>
        <td class="value">06/22/1994</td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td class="title">Country</td>
    <td class="value"><a title="used Lako semi-trailer PORTUGAL" href="/lako-semi-trailer/portugal/~a1b35e2161nPT/lako-portugal.html" onclick="gtag('event', 'click', {'event_category': 'technicalSheet', 'event_label': 'listing-country', 'value': '1'});">PORTUGAL</a></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td class="title">Manufacturer</td>
    <td class="value"><a title="used Lako" href="/used-lako/~a1e2161/ads.html" onclick="gtag('event', 'click', {'event_category': 'technicalSheet', 'event_label': 'listing-fam-brd', 'value': ''});">Lako</a></td>
</tr></tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used ancestor

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//td[contains(text(),"Make")]//ancestor::tr/td[@class="value"]').text
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an xpath, you can use `driver.find_element_by_css_selector`, anchoring your search on the parent `tr` of `"Make"`:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('tbody > tr:nth-of-type(3) a')
```

Should the `tr` with `"Make"` vary in position across pages, you can also use `driver.execute_script` to run a custom Javascript snippet:

```
result = driver.execute_script("""
  for (var i of document.querySelectorAll('tbody > tr')){
    if (i.querySelector('td.title').textContent === 'Make'){
       return i.querySelector('td.value a').textContent;
    }
  }
""")
```

Comment: Hi @Ajax1234,

Many thanks for your reply, the location of the tr varies, I tried your javascript snippet but that does not work on my side i get the error message : cannot read properties of null (reading 'textContent')

 (or i am doing that incorrectly I am a noob just restarted again with Selenium) 

Never embedded Javascript aswell in Python so i am learning here aswell :)